# How to pull Google Analytics stats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is [Google API Ruby client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) the best option?

I have a site example.com with users and I want them to see their google analytics stats on example.com, how can I do it ?

I can see [the example](https://gist.github.com/joost/5344705) but I'm not able to figure out how to begin.

Comment: Legato has _not ever_ been abandoned, and is a better way to build maintainable queries against the GA API. I've asked the author of that Gist to correct his erroneous notes. Legato has _always_ supported GA API Version 3. https://github.com/tpitale/legato/commit/0def82f9bdb9cf259d4d91d5bd2f17759231bb29

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I also use the *google-api-ruby-client* gem and set it up about the same way that is outlined in the link you provided (https://gist.github.com/joost/5344705).

Just follow the steps outlined in the link to set up a Google Analytics client:

```
# you need to set this according to your situation/needs
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS = '...' # looks like 12345@developer.gserviceaccount.com
PATH_TO_KEY_FILE              = '...' # the path to the downloaded .p12 key file
PROFILE                       = '...' # your GA profile id, looks like 'ga:12345'


require 'google/api_client'

# set up a client instance
client  = Google::APIClient.new

client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience             => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope                => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
  :issuer               => SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
  :signing_key          => Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(PATH_TO_KEY_FILE, 'notasecret')
).tap { |auth| auth.fetch_access_token! }

api_method = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3').data.ga.get


# make queries
result = client.execute(:api_method => api_method, :parameters => {
  'ids'        => PROFILE,
  'start-date' => Date.new(1970,1,1).to_s,
  'end-date'   => Date.today.to_s,
  'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
  'metrics'    => 'ga:pageviews',
  'filters'    => 'ga:pagePath==/url/to/user'
})

puts result.data.rows.inspect
```

To display statistics for a user's page in your app, you have to adjust the *metrics* and *filters* parameters when making the query. The query above for example will return a result object containing all pageviews for the page with url *example.com/url/to/user*.

---

**Caveat:** this answer was written a long time ago and Google released a new, incompatible version of the gem. Please consult https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md

Comment: Saved my day.. Thanks @severin. In the make query section, PROILE should be spelled as PROFILE. Not a big deal though.

Comment: @severin what is "PROFILE = '...' # your GA profile id, looks like 'ga:12345' "?

from where did you took that id?

is that analytics account id.?
if so do we need to prefix with it 'ga:'.?

Comment: @severin when i ran "api_method = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3').data.ga.get"
its leading to
unknown keyword: interval
from /home/brahmos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/google-api-client-0.7.1/lib/google/api_client.rb:595:in `execute!'

Comment: @h.APP.y you find the profile id by navigating to "Admin", then go to "View settings" for your view; there you should see a "View ID": this is the profile id (Google renamed this from profile id to view id), e.g. "12345". You then have to set PROFILE to "ga:12345".

Comment: @severin got it. Thank you. i was tiered by searching.

Comment: It returns an empty array. Can you help me.

Comment: I solved it. I used Account ID instead of ID in the View settings.

Comment: LoadError in DashboardController#show cannot load such file -- google/api_client

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Bengala my answer works with the google-api-client gem versions up to version 0.8. If you installed version 0.9 of the gem then you have to adapt it. Consult https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md